# mongoid, set_table_name & attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, tablename, attr-accessible

I'm using rails3 edge and mongoid 2beta6 with ruby 1.9.2-head.

How can I manually change the table name, just like set_table_name for ActiveRecord? For example my model Signup should use the table "users" for storage, not "signups".

Another question is how to implement the bevahior of attr_accessible AR provides?

Thanks,
Corin

Answer (score 7):

Pretty simple :)

Change:

```rb
class Pictures
  self.collection_name = 'photos'
end
```

To:

```rb
class Pictures
   store_in collection: 'photos'
end
```

Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-documents/#storage

Comment: Mongoid now also provides `store_in`, as in: `store_in :photos` which accepts an options hash.  http://mongoid.org/docs/documents.html

Comment: Link above has changed to: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-documents/#storage

Answer (score 1):

With mongoid, as far as I know `attr_accessible` is ignored.
Only attributes that you declare with `field` will be persisted, however if they are passed as an attribute, you can use `attr_accessor` to make sure those will not be persist (typically :password as an example).

Alex

Answer (score 0):

The link mentioned by  [Dan Healy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646219/dan-healy) was changed to  http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html.